# IOS Cant Reposition UIImageView at runtime

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, position

I have looked at other questions on SO regarding this issue and my code seems to follow the provided solutions so I don't know Where I am going wrong.
I ma trying to reset the position of an image view when the screen loads. the size will depend on the a base image.

The image always remains where it was placed in interface builder. There are no constraints on the image view.

Does it matter where i call this From? i have tried `viewDidLoad()` , `viewWillLoad()` And `viewDidAppear()`

**Code**

```
@IBOutlet weak var cameraPreview: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var glassesOverlay: UIImageView!

    print("Before")
    print("overlay x: \(glassesOverlay.frame.origin.x)")
    print("overlay y: \(glassesOverlay.frame.origin.y)")
    print("overlay W: \(glassesOverlay.frame.width)")
    print("overlay H: \(glassesOverlay.frame.height)")


    let glassesOrigin = CGPointMake( (cameraPreview.frame.width / 2) - (glassesOverlay.frame.width / 2), cameraPreview.frame.height / 3)

    //let glassesOrigin = CGPointMake( 179.0, 179.0)
    let glassesWidth = cameraPreview.frame.width / 2.0
    let glassesSize = CGSizeMake(glassesWidth, glassesWidth / 4)

    //        glassesOverlay.frame.origin =  CGPointMake( (cameraPreview.frame.width / 2) - (glassesOverlay.frame.width / 2), cameraPreview.frame.height / 3)
    //        glassesOverlay.frame.size = glassesSize

    glassesOverlay.frame = CGRect(origin: glassesOrigin, size: glassesSize)

    //cameraPreview.subviews[0].frame = CGRect(origin: glassesOrigin, size: glassesSize)
    glassesOverlay.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor
    glassesOverlay.layer.borderWidth = 2.0

    cameraPreview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purpleColor().CGColor
    cameraPreview.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    print("After")
    print("overlay x: \(glassesOverlay.frame.origin.x)")
    print("overlay y: \(glassesOverlay.frame.origin.y)")
    print("overlay W: \(glassesOverlay.frame.width)")
    print("overlay H: \(glassesOverlay.frame.height)")
```

as you can see i have tried explicitly setting values with the same result. i am printing the position and dimensions before and after and they print the changed values.

**Print Output**

```
Before
overlay x: 135.0
overlay y: 382.0
overlay W: 320.0
overlay H: 128.0
After
overlay x: 224.0
overlay y: 296.667
overlay W: 384.0
overlay H: 96.0
```

But it remains unmoved.

Comment: Can you add the above code in viewDidLayoutSubviews()?

Comment: @Vishnugondlekar Thanks for the input but this did not work the only effect it had was the code block was called twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using auto layout? Then modify the constraints instead of manipulating the frame directly. After modifying the constraints, you need to

```
view.setNeedsLayout()
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

If you are not using auto layout, this should work, except the old frame is matching the new frame or the outlet is holding another view than you expect.

**Edit**:

Please have a look at [how autolayout works](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html). There are good WWDC videos explaining it as well.

Comment: Honestly i dont know anything about auto layout (this is my first ios project). I know that the parent view is positioned in the storyboard using constraints and the child (the image view) is just placed in the parent no constraints.

Comment: Then you are using auto layout. Try to add the constraints that position the view in interface builder (relevant to the other view) - no code required.

Comment: I was doing it in code as i the position to be the same in preview as it is when i sae the combined/merged images(parent and child). if i set it using constraints will i be able to place itthe same way? `width = half parent width`, `x = halh parent width - half child width`, `y = 1/3 parent height`

Comment: You can define constraints relative to one at most one other view in IB. Yet, you can add constant leading, top, height and width constraints and set their constants accordingly in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: So you can set them in IB and then reset them in the controller?

Comment: Yes, just create IBOutlets for the constraints as you did with the views.